# Trying to configure monit to use https protocol but it sticks with http

Tags: apache-http-server, https, centos-7, httpd, monit

I'm trying to monitor a VHost on the local Apache instance via Monit. The same domain accepts both **http** *and* **https** traffic, so I wanted to monitor both.

Also, the IP that the domain resolves to goes to a server that load balances the traffic between the current Apache instance and another server running Apache. I need Monit to monitor the *local* instance, and I was hoping to avoid adding any records in the */etc/hosts* file, so I was thinking that Monits config setting `with http headers []` would suffice, and I think it is (Just monitoring *localhost*, but setting the headers `Host` to the vhost domain).

Anyways, the main problem I seem to be running into, is even though I configure Monit to monitor the host via both **http** and **https** protocols, it monitors both hosts via just **http**, however the port is set to 443 for the one I need using **https** protocol.

The Monit config file for Apache is:

```
check process httpd with pidfile /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
    start program = "/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/bin/systemctl stop httpd.service"

check host localhost with address localhost
    if failed
        port 80
        protocol http
        with http headers [Host: www.domain.com, Cache-Control: no-cache]
        and request / with content = "www.domain.com"
            then restart
    if failed
        port 443
        protocol https
        with http headers [Host: www.domain.com, Cache-Control: no-cache]
        and request / with content = "www.domain.com"
            then restart
    if 5 restarts within 5 cycles
        then timeout
```

And here's the Monit status for that check:

```
[root@server enabled-monitors]# monit status localhost
The Monit daemon 5.14 uptime: 14m

Remote Host 'localhost'
  status                            Connection failed
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  port response time                FAILED to [localhost]:443/ type TCPSSL/IP protocol HTTP
  port response time                0.001s to [localhost]:80/ type TCP/IP protocol HTTP
  data collected                    Tue, 26 Apr 2016 10:44:32
```

So it's fairly obvious to me that the https is failing because its still trying to use port HTTP, even though I have `protocol https` in the configuration.

Any input would be much appreciated. I have a feeling this may be a bug, and ill create an issue in the Monit Github repo, but I wan't to make sure it's not something silly that I overlooked.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this? I just encountered the same thing. Looks like a bug in monit tbh

Answer (score 0):

Header doesn't work here, so i only use a simple check:

```
...
  if failed host www.host.com port 80 protocol http
    and request "/index.html"
    with timeout 25 seconds
    for 4 times within 5 cycles
    then restart
  if failed host www.host.com port 443 protocol https
    and request "/index.html"
    with timeout 25 seconds
    for 4 times within 5 cycles
    then restart
...
```